# Why sma is so different with wma in for loop with pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to sum MA like below with tradingview's pinescript.
But, results are quite different.
wma one is correct, but sma one is strange..
Any idea?

```
sum_ma = 0
for i = 1 to 30
    sum_ma := sum_ma + i * sma(close[i], 1)
plot(sum_ma)

sum_ma := 0
for i = 1 to 30
    sum_ma := sum_ma + i * wma(close[i], 1)
plot(sum_ma)
```

Comment: what do you mean strange ? They are supposed to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sma` has a problem. Use `sma` written in pine instead:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")

pine_sma(src, len) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        sum := sum + src[i] / len
    sum

sum_ma = 0.0
for i = 1 to 30
    sum_ma := sum_ma + i * pine_sma(close[i], 1)
plot(sum_ma, color=blue)

sum_ma := 0
for i = 1 to 30
    sum_ma := sum_ma + i * wma(close[i], 1)
plot(sum_ma, color=red)
```

Comment: @michel-t Thank you so much